# Change URL of wordpress post?

Tags: wordpress

I am using wordpress for the first time, the problem is that when i post any article the url come to be is
"sitename.com/?p=XXX"
I want it should show the name of the article in the url. How can i change it. Please give a noob friendly answer

Answer (score 2):

Had over to this article on how to do that :)

[SEO Friendly URL Structure for WordPress](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/seo-friendly-url-structure-for-wordpress/)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use clean urls from the setting ...

Look here :
http://interaction.dundee.ac.uk/~ali/blog/nice-clean-urls-in-wordpress/

Following links can can provide you more insight :

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/clean-urls-and-htaccess

http://www.guyrutenberg.com/2008/05/24/clean-urls-permalinks-for-wordpress-on-lighttpd/

But please do not use this site for such type of questions.
Its a site for asking programming questions .

Please refer FAQ :
https://stackoverflow.com/faq